# performSelector or directly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, performselector

I understand that these both are bit similar, but there must be any internal difference between two,

```
[anObject performSelector:@selector(thisMethod:) withObject:passedObject];
```

is equivalent to:

```
[anObject thisMethod:passedObject];
```

Please tell me what is the differnce in terms of compilation, memory etc.

Comment: The latter is more flexible as it allows you to supply more than two parameters (performSelector:withObject:withObject:).

Comment: But we can pass dozens of objects packed in an array as 1 parameter.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya yikes, DONT. For such scenarios one shall use `NSInvocation`.

Comment: @Till: I agree, but for such a strange question answer can be this :D

Comment: In the end, all given options compile towards objc_msgSend -> no difference in speed or other resource consumption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `performSelector` family of methods are for special cases, the vast majority of method invocations in Obj-C should be direct. Some differences:

*Indirect:* When using `performSelector` to invoke a method you have two method invocations; that of `performSelector` and the target method.

*Arguments are objects:* When invoking via `performSelector` all arguments must be passed as objects, e.g. if invoking a method which takes a `double` then that value must be wrapped as an `NSNumber` before being passed to `performSelector`. The `performSelector` methods unwraps non-object arguments before calling the target method. In direct invocation no wrapping or unwrapping is required.

*Only two arguments:* The `performSelector` family only includes variants which pass 0, 1 or 2 arguments so you cannot use them to invoke a method which takes 3 or more arguments.

You probably see most of the above as negatives, so what are the benefits?

*Dynamic selector:* The `performSelector` family allow you to invoke a method which is not known until runtime, only its *type* need be known (so you can pass the right arguments and get the right result); in other words the selector argument may be an *expression* of type `SEL`. This might be used when you wish to pass a method as an argument to another method and invoke it. **However** if you are compiling with ARC using dynamic selectors is non-trivial and usually produces compiler warnings, as without knowing the selector ARC cannot know the ownership attributes of the arguments.

*Delayed execution:* The `performSelector` family includes methods which invoke the method after a delay.

In general use direct method invocation, only if that does not give you what you require do you need to consider the `performSelector` family (or its even more esoteric cousins).

Answer (score 3):

`performSelector:withObject:` will be slightly slower than calling the method directly.  The indirection also means that the compiler can't do proper type checking.  With ARC enabled, you'll also run into issues where the compiler will complain because it is impossible to determine exactly what the memory management policy might be.

In general, such indirection -- often called *reflection* but more accurately referred to as *meta-programming* -- is to be avoided exactly because it moves what should be compile time detectable failures to runtime failures.

Such dynamism is only needed when the name of the selector -- the name of the method -- being called *cannot be determined at compile time*.   It should not be used for `@optional` methods in protocols nor should it be used during delegation (in both cases, `respondsToSelector:` + a direct method call are a far better pattern to employ).

Comment: Out of curiosity, I've been simply suppressing that warning, but are there any ARC implications that I should be taking into consideration?  I don't think the methods return any objects (only CGFloat or void)

Comment: @borrrden: "I don't think the methods return any objects (only CGFloat or void)" Then you cannot use `performSelector:`. It only returns objects (void is probably okay). The ARC implications are only if you use `performSelector:` to call something like `alloc`, `retain`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` or something similar with unusual memory management rules.

Comment: Whoops, I was using NSInvocation for the CGFloat ones @newacct .  All the other ones are void.  I figured it was for some less obvious cases, though.  I don't see any leaks in my program.

Comment: Frankly, we've moved away from using performSelector: (and various permutations) entirely. Opting for block/queue based patterns for the after delay variants.  For truly dynamic calls, we use a cast variant of `objc_msgSend()`.  Works just like `performSelector:`'s immediate forms, but has compiler type safety and zero overhead.   The casting implies exact API contract, too.

Answer (score 1):

The `performSelector:` method allows you to send messages that aren’t determined until runtime. For more info read [this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your app wants to make use of `reflection`, where in by changing some values in configuration file you want to invoke a different method (Different adapters). Or based on object type you would like to invoke a different method on runtime.

If you developing a customizable product this a powerful feature.

Comment: Which also will lead to plenty of warnings by the compiler and possible memory management problems as the method signatures are not known at compile time.

Comment: That's always there, it's a trade off between ease of development and extensibility.

Answer (score -1):

I like to use [id performSelecter:selector withObject] when declare and implements a custom protocol,and delegate pattern, its also an use case, where we should use performselector rather then direct calling the method...

Comment: `performSelector:` should not be used with protocols or delegates.  You have the method declaration in both cases, thus the selector is known and can be invoked directly.